# Updating Android Material Components version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0, color all messed up

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components, material-components-android

After I update the material components version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.1, the colors inside app messed up. For example color accent not working, buttons color not applied, bottom navigation view become black color.. Please help, thanks in advance!

values/style.xml (style here not working):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="Button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/button_radius</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lato_regular_400</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
<style name="Button.Next">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lato_bold_700</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_18pxsp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/_40sdp</item>
</style>
```

values-v23/style.xml (style here is working):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

button.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        style="@style/Button.Next"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:onClick="@{click}"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20pxdp"
        android:text="@{buttonText}" />
```

But even the v23 style is working, the colors all still very strange, compare to before update material components version. Very hard to apply back the same colors.

Comment: It is quite difficult to help you without details. Post your app theme and for example a layout with a button to start.

Comment: Your MaterialButton should have a colorPrimary as background and colorOnPrimary as text color.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti but I don't have this issue when using "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0", is this a new format for version 1.1.0? The styles actually working, just the colors not working.

Comment: The 1.1.0 changes a lot of features in the library (the 1.0.0 was released 1 year ago) and changes the theme.
Try to use a [Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes-bridge-themes) in your case.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks but still not really working.. Gonna do more researches

Comment: did it work for you @yao?

Comment: @Rashad.Z sorry I ended up gave up on updating it..

Comment: @yao you can check my answer on supporting dark and light theme in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/60093738/1950784

Answer (score 2):

We have officially Material Components 1.1.0

Try to use `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge"`

Take a look at documentation. 
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes-bridge-themes

If you cannot change your theme to inherit from a Material Components theme, you can inherit from a Material Components Bridge theme.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="**Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge**">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

In your case change:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
```

Comment: Bridge worked for me but only for a part. The textcolor in my appbar has changed and "colorOnPrimary" in my theme has not resolved my problem. ideas?