# Supporting Dark & Light Theme in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

I currently use the following parent theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` and just updated my material design library to

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`

which messed up some colors in my app

So i am deciding to update it to support both light and dark themes. I will post what i did to achieve this to save some time for others searching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After performing some searches, this is what i did in details

**Change the parent theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

---

- Remove all background colors, text colors etc... where its necessary
- add colors this way: `"?android:attr/colorBackground"`, `"?attr/colorOnBackground"`, `"?attr/colorSurface"` where needed

---

**To change some colors in-code then use this function**

```
    fun getColor(context: Context, colorResId: Int): Int {
       val typedValue = TypedValue()
       val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, intArrayOf(colorResId))
       val color = typedArray.getColor(0, 0)
       typedArray.recycle()
       return color
    }
```

**Example**:

`setTextColor(Utils.getColor(context, R.attr.colorError))`

---

- Add values-night directory if necessary to support different colors in dark and night mode
- Add colors.xml file inside the directory and then just override any color written in colors.xml

**Example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1f2021</color>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Dark Theme:**

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

**For Normal Theme:**

```
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

You can set theme according to your needs in oncreate and button click etc..

**styles.xml** of `values` folder

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black </item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Add Folder to `res` folder name `values-night` in that add `color.xml` and `style.xml` to your need.
**styles.xml** of `values-night` folder

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangeDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

`color.xml` of `values` folder

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="daynight_textColor">#6cbabb</color>

</resources>
```

`color.xml` of `values-night` folder

```
<resources>
 <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="daynight_textColor">#ff8222</color>
</resources>
```